# Substitute for Robin Eggs malted milk candy

Tags: substitutions, candy

This summer, we made some great malted milk ice cream and mixed in some crushed Robin Eggs that we'd bought on sale after Easter. I'd love to make the same ice cream again, but the problem is: it's not Easter and I can't find Robin Eggs anywhere.

Are there other candy that I could use? I don't think regular milk balls would work as well since they don't have the same malted milk to chocolate ratio, and I'm more interested in the malted milk part than the chocolate part. The candy coating adds a nice crunch and color as well, but that's more of a bonus than requirement.

I know there are some online stores that sell them year round, but they tend to be pretty expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [Whoppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoppers). There's no crunchy candy exterior and the chocolate is somewhat thinner (I think), but those seemed to be low on your list of requirements.

They are somewhat unusual to find in grocery stores, but you may be able to find fun-size packs easily in post-Halloween sales.

Comment: You could perhaps supplement the Whoppers with some regular crushed M&Ms, which will give you both the extra chocolate and the candy coating to tweak the ratios to your desire.

Comment: I think the idea was to *not* have too much chocolate.

Comment: Finally got around to making the ice cream and used Whoppers and it came out great! I don't think I miss the crunchy candy coating enough to bother with M&Ms next time either.

Answer (score 3):

You could use malt ball 'centers,' which are not coated in chocolate. They're available online from a variety of sources, often those selling nuts or candy in bulk, such as [Nuts.com](https://nuts.com/chocolatessweets/malted-milk-balls/malt-ball-centers.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&scid=scplp2862334&sc_intid=05480-01&gclid=CKLPvbPQ7s8CFYg6gQodqSUO_w). As @Megha suggests, the addition of a handful of chopped M&Ms would give you the candy coating crunch and a small amount of chocolate.